Use multiple hibernate version in Wildfly
I have an old deployment that uses hibernate 3.5.0. I'm trying to host it on Wildfly 26. The problem this wildfly is using hibernate 5.3. I can't migrate the JAR cause I don't have the code and I want to host it on that wildfly.
I created the wildfly 3.5.0 modules (name: org.hibernate.legacy) and provide it in the persistent.xml.
<persistence-unit name="grh">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/myDatasource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate.legacy" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>-->            
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/myEntityManagerFactory"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

Running Wildfly I get this error and I don't understand why is it still using org.hibernate@5.3.28.Final:
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to construct requested dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect (org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect is in unnamed module of loader 'org.hibernate.legacy@3.5.0-Final' @5838fb5b; org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect is in unnamed module of loader 'org.hibernate@5.3.28.Final' @275d3093)"
I created a jboss-deployment-structure.xml``file in the META-INF` folder of the ear deployment:
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
        <module name="org.hibernate" />
    </exclusions>
    <dependencies>
      <module name="org.hibernate.legacy" />
    </dependencies>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>


Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366440/jboss-wildfly-hibernate-3-classloading, it's quite old but it might give hints to solve your depencency clash.

No it's not. I did the exact thing but it's still referencing to org.hibernate@5.3.28.Final

Which WIldfly version are you using, exactly, since there is a range between 26.0.0.Final and 26.1.3.Final, to try to replicate your error?

I'm using wildfly-26.1.3.Final. With javax supported.
